# catkin_make error using rgbdsalm_v2 kinect ONE (v2)

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-kinetic, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am running ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 on an Intel NUC and I am trying to use a kinect one (kinect v2) to generate 3D point clouds. I have soldered 12V and ground leads to pin 10 and ground and am using a 3.0 USB cable to the NUC. I have verified that the Kinect V2 is working by installing the driver libfreenect2 and executed `bash ./bin/Protonect` which gave me four feeds of the different sensors.

I installed rgbdslam_v2 from here using the install.sh which seemed to work and installed g2ofork too. I then exported the environment variable `export G2O_DIR=home/astrobotics/ros_code/src/g2ofork`, and attempted to `catkin_make`

the error I am getting is at the bottom of the catkin_make output

```
-- The imported target "vtk" references the file
   "/usr/bin/vtk"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.2/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- Searching for g2o ...
-- Searching for g2o in home/astrobotics/ros_code/src/g2ofork
CMake Error at rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam/cmake-modules/FindG2O.cmake:78 (message):
  Could not find libg2o!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt:91 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/astrobotics/ros_code/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/astrobotics/ros_code/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:4140: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

It seems like it cannot find libg2o. does anyone have any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284301/catkin_make-error-using-rgbdsalm_v2-kinect-one-(v2)/) by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-04**:
Something to consider for the future: about 90% of the log shows warnings, and only the last 10 lines had an error (which is also the only error directly mentioning `g2o`). It might be best to post excerpts in the beginning, and only relevant parts. Forum members will ask for more if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> export G2O_DIR=home/astrobotics/ros_code/src/g2ofork
> ```

This is a guess, but you're probably missing a forward slash (`/`) here at the beginning of the path. It should be `/home/astrobotics/..`.

Right now it's relative to whatever the `CWD` is, which is probably not what you want./intended.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) on 2018-03-05**:
@gvdhoorn thank you for the advice; I updated the question and the / before the directory was the issue.